# Creating Dynamic, Unique Arrays Dependent on Multiple Criteria or Subset of Data

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, named-ranges

I have a **Table** structured in this manner:

```
City    Region    Date   Value
ABC     123       Jan1   10%
DEF     999       Feb1   7%
```

The table is fed by **user-entry**, but there is an important rule:

1. No region can have more than one of the same date, even if the values are different.

To control this, I utilize two formulas:

1. A Dynamic Named Range that creates a list of unique dates.
2. A conditional formatting rule that flags entries that have duplicate dates.

I am having trouble with #1. #2 I have tested to work fine.

My attempt was to create this named range, simply called UniqueDates.

```
=OFFSET(
    OFFSET(Table!$C$9,0,0,1,1),
        MATCH(0,
        COUNTIF(Table[@Region],Entry[Region]),0)
    -1,0,
    SUM(COUNTIFS(Table[Region],Entry[@Region]))
)
```

I have experimented with trying different criteria combinations, but cannot seem to create a list of unique dates that have been entered thus far. Instead, I get either the wrong dates, or non-distinct results.

It is important to note that the result of this formula is not stored in Data Validation. I take it directly to the conditional formatting rule.

Answer (score 1):

I over-complicated the problem. The solution was simply to drop named ranges altogether and do the duplication check within the Conditional Formatting rule itself:

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("Table[Date]"),INDIRECT("Table[@Date]"),INDIRECT("Table[Region]"),INDIRECT("Table[@Date]"))>1
```